# CSS not formatted correctly in vagrant environment

Tags: css, ubuntu, nfs, vagrant

I have vagrant setup as my local dev environment. When vagrant is up and I edit my CSS file and look at its source in the browser **the new CSS I have written is not in the file and the file is now appended by loads of question marks**:

```
��������������������������
```

If I do vagrant halt or destroy and then bring it back up the CSS file is fine with the new code visible and formatted correctly and no sign of the question marks. As soon as I edit it again the same things happens. Obviously I don't want to destroy and create vagrant every time I make a CSS change.

Any ideas on this?

**Update**: I have been told this may be to do with not having NFS installed with vagrant - I am on ubuntu and my files are within an encrypted home directory so I believe NFS doesn't work - any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had lot of problems with not having nfs activated on my VM

What information do you have when you run a 'ls -la  file.css' on the file ?

Comment: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 colin colin 649 Jul 20 14:29 style.css`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can disable sendfile based on this thread:

[JS and CSS files in vagrant not properly encoded when saved outside of the VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782946/js-and-css-files-in-vagrant-not-properly-encoded-when-saved-outside-of-the-vm)

Set enableSendFile to off in httpd.conf.