# JS and CSS files in vagrant not properly encoded when saved outside of the VM

Tags: apache, character-encoding, centos, vagrant

I'm running vagrant on OSX, Ubuntu, and Windows 7 and using vim and Netbeans as IDEs on the host machine. The VM is running CentOS 6.3 and Apache 2.2. The docroot is set to `/vagrant`.

When I edit a JS or CSS file and save it, the browser then turns around and detects illegal characters. When I view the file in the browser I see the diamond-question mark character which usually points to an encoding issue. I can open the file up in vim inside the VM and save it with `:w ++enc=utf-8` and the file will load normally.

I've tried multiple IDEs on the host machine and different host OSes, and can only pinpoint it to something to do with vagrant and the mounted directory. My IDEs aren't the problem as I can run the files locally and they work, or save them to a remote machine and the files work. Only when I save them to what gets mounted in `/vagrant` do I have a problem.

Is it Apache or something else in the OS that I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Post your apache response headers

Comment: Same case but with `nginx` as web server and getting same issue, so I don't think its related to nginx, `dos2unix` also worked for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant/VirtualBox/Apache2 Strange Cache Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479117/vagrant-virtualbox-apache2-strange-cache-behaviour)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had this problem this morning.  Set EnableSendfile to off in your httpd.conf.

If you look at your httpd.conf it says "turn this off if you serve from NFS-mounted filesystems."  In http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile it explains that "By default, when the handling of a request requires no access to the data within a file -- for example, when delivering a static file -- Apache uses sendfile to deliver the file contents without ever reading the file if the OS supports it."

Since your windows host has an ntfs file system, the linux guest doesn't properly cache the file with sendfile and so apache needs to send the file itself.  This may cause a marginal slowdown when requesting files from apache, but it should be negligible.

Comment: Same issue on Nginx with OS X as host. Again, setting `sendfile off;` in nginx.conf fixed this.

Comment: worked for me too! although make sure, if you're using vagrant, that you `vagrant reload` so the changes to the `nginx.conf` file will update.

Comment: @John_McCombs you are my god for today :). In my case it was `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Ran into this issue on OS X host, boot2docker, Docker, and Apache running inside a container. `EnableSendfile off` fixes the issue there as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: After 18 hours of trying to work out what the hell was going on, your post saved me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what server you are using.

For **Nginx**: in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

change the line that contains `sendfile on;` to `sendfile off;`.

For **Apache**: in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

change remove comment for `EnableSendfile off;`

And **don't** forget `restart` your Nginx or Apache. If it still doesn't work,  `exit` and `vagrant reload` or something like that -  restart your VM.