# nginx on Ubuntu in Vagrant VM stops sending JS file randomly in the middle

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, nginx, vagrant

I've run into this repeatedly on different deployments, same issue every time.

I'm running nginx inside Ubuntu, on a vagrant box (ubuntu/trusty64).  JS files never fully send.  If I cat the files on the box, the entire content is there, but when I check (with chrome web dev tools) the content of what the browser receives for that file, it stops long before the end.

I don't know if this is an IDE (PHPStorm / WebStorm) issue, an nginx issue, ubuntu issue, or a vagrant limitation (I'm leaning towards either a PHPStorm/WebStorm issue, or an nginx issue... even though I've used the exact same nginx/site config on a non-Vagrant box and it seems to work fine).

Has anyone else run into this before or does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sigh.  Of course I find the answer right after posting the question.

I found the answer in: [JS and CSS files in vagrant not properly encoded when saved outside of the VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782946/js-and-css-files-in-vagrant-not-properly-encoded-when-saved-outside-of-the-vm)

Comment by [adwww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266986/adwww): "Same issue on Nginx with OS X as host. Again, setting sendfile off; in nginx.conf fixed this."