# Vagrant, CSS not updated

Tags: apache, debian, vagrant

So I'm using Vagrant and shared folders and when I update the .css file I dont get changes on the website. Instead I get encoded characters like question marks ��.

I searched through the web and found a solution, but that solution doesnt work for me.

The solution was to add "EnableSendfile off" in apache2.conf file. I'm using debian btw. I added this, restarted apache, reloaded vagrant and still nothing got solved.

I created this topic because I cant comment on the existing ones because I still dont have 50 reputation. Please dont hate me for that.

Can you tell me why it doesnt work for me? What else can I do to fix this. It stupid to continue reloading vagrant for few css chagnes.

Best Regards

Comment: Is it just CSS files that this is happening with, or any file type?

Comment: I also have same issue, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue.

Remove comment for this line in file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf in Vagrant:

```
EnableSendfile off
```

Check this for more details (same issue): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403744/4728084

Comment: @Glats I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that refreshing in Chrome by using Ctr F5 will also load the CSS file.